# How to stop click event through a semi transparent background?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to set a semi-transparent view over another view when user click on a certain button. And at the same time I want my background view not to be clickable. 
     So basically I am setting alpha as 0.9 to my foreground view.

**Code**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_fg_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#231564"
    android:alpha="0.9"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

and below this view there is a listview. So when user click on a button this view will pop up but at the same time background view (i.e. ListView) also clickable at the same time.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Set `android:clickable="true"` in xml to your foreground view.

Answer (score 2):

If somebody needs to do this with a cardView widget, then try:

```
android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the attribute `android:filterTouchesWhenObscured` to `true`. That should work.